# android studio asks for install emulator which already installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

android studio asks for install emulator which already installed

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: You can avoid it!

Comment: i did but when i try to run the virtual device this error messege popup {Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
No emulator installed

Please download the emulator}

Answer (score 0):

Try this File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart.
Hope this helps